# Can't run sh "for-do-done" loop in the Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, sh

I have a file named **volumes** with the list of volumes, separated by space. Here is an example of the file content

```
vol-0e9cd38819c7a6cb8 vol-0baba5cee0c7fc89a vol-0e7fae905aaffe3a1
```

I can delete all of them by using this loop in **sh**:

```
for volume in $(cat volumes); do; aws ec2 delete-volume --volume-id $volume; done
```

But when I try to do it inside of the Jenkinsfile like this:

```
sh "for volume in \$(cat volumes); do; aws ec2 delete-volume --volume-id \$volume; done"
```

I get the following error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

I've tried to escape the characters in different ways and also different types of the **sh** block, but it doesn't help, I still get the same error.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Your sh loop is invalid. Copy it into a terminal and try to run.

Comment: It works, just checked it in the terminal:
for volume in $(cat volumes); do; aws ec2 delete-volume --volume-id $volume; done

Comment: You must have typed it in multiple lines, or you are not running `sh`.

Comment: You are right, I am actually running zsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `;` after `do`. It's:

```
for volume in $(cat volumes); do aws ec2 delete-volume --volume-id $volume; done
```

`for i in $(cat` is an **anti** pattern. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 . In this case I would use xargs.

```
xargs -n1 aws ec2 delete-volume --volume-id < volumes
```